# CSS increase font size

Tags: css

I'm a no expert in CSS, but have this task to increase font size on the site.
The site uses a downloaded CSS-theme. As I see there is a single file main.css which contains definitions of fonts. In other css-files font-size is set using percentages.

However, there are 102 matches for the word `font-size` in main.css itself, because it sets sizes for all possible html elements and their combinations, like

```
 body { font-size: 13px; }
 h1 { font-size: 32px; }
 h1.smaller { font-size: 31px; }
 h2 { font-size: 26px; }
```

and so on.

I am thinking to write a script that would extract values of font-size `$1` and replace them with `$1+1`.

In a while, probably there is a more elegant solution? Maybe I can redefine font sizes some way using CSS itself?

Comment: This is why it is discouraged to use hard-coded pixel values. Generally speaking, it is better to use `em` units instead. Then, you could specify a "baseline` font-size at the beginning of the CSS file on the `html` element, and all fonts would scale from there.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but I have no choice here. I have what I have.

Comment: So you want to do this just once (via an editor)? Or programmatically (via JavaScript or whatever)?

Comment: @xaxa I'm suggesting that you go through and change them to em sizes now. You can calculate the em value with your script idea.

Comment: Why don't you just add !important to your properties? That way the properties you define will be considered.

Comment: @putvande, it shouldn't be changable by user or application. But possibly not once - maybe, `$1+1` still will be too small, so I'll have to increase it `$1+2`...

Comment: @xaxa to convert from `px to em`, just do `px / 16px = em`. i.e. `32px / 16px = 2.0em`

Comment: @AbhishekBiswal, could you be more specific? As I said, I'm no expert in CSS. Do you want me to redefine all these combinations?

Comment: @xaxa for example : in your css file use : h1.smaller { font-size: 10px !important; } This way, the browser will ignore all other font sizes defined for h1.smaller and use 10px / whatever you define.

Comment: @AbhishekBiswal, since I'll have to write script to do this anyway, I'd probably go with what crush suggested

Comment: @xaxa What language would you like the script?

Comment: Doesnt matter actually) I thought ruby...

Comment: If you have this script right at your hand, it is OK)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the following PHP script to convert all `font-size: [0-9]+px` values into `em`:

```
<?php

$filename = "MyCss.css";

$css = file_get_contents($filename);

$css = preg_replace('/font-size\s*\:\s*([0-9]+)\s*px/ie', '"font-size: " . ($1/16) . "em"', $css);

file_put_contents($filename, $css);
```

Your example CSS above became:

```
body { font-size: 0.8125em; }
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
h1.smaller { font-size: 1.9375em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.625em; }
```

I'd then recommend setting a `baseline` font-size on the HTML element:

```
html { font-size: 16px; }
```

Then, if you want to globally affect all font sizes on the page, you can change this single value, and all fonts using `em` units will scale.

You could also use percentages if you'd rather, but `em`'s are usually preferred.

(Sorry, Ruby is one of the few languages I don't know)

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you very much!) Language doesnt matter.

Comment: Em and percentages are equivalent as far as font-sizes go, the only preference is personal (`100% == 1em`, `120% == 1.2em`).  There's no reason to set a font-size on the html element if what you really want is the browser's default font-size (which users who know how to adjust their font-sizes will prefer).

Comment: @cimmanon Setting a font-size on the html element will serve as a baseline for the entire page. If it is not set, then it will default to `100% == 16px == 1.0em` which users can scale further with the zoom functionality of their browser, as you have stated. Therefore, by setting `HTML { font-size: 12px; }` then `1.0em` becomes `12px` instead of `16px`, as it is all relative to the descendents.

Comment: That said, there might be some repercussions from the above code dealing with css descendents. For example, it does not take into account the scenario: `table { font-size: 20px; } td { font-size: 15px; }`. The above code would cause this to become `table { font-size: 1.25em; /* 20px */} td { font-size: 0.9375em; /* 18.75px */}` because em's are relative to their parent.

Comment: That's all well and good except for the part where you've stomped all over the user's preferences.  There are many people who want to increase their font size to something they can read *without* having to resort to zooming.  (see: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/, http://csswizardry.com/2011/05/font-sizing-with-rem-could-be-avoided/, http://ia.net/blog/100e2r, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/16-pixels-body-copy-anything-less-costly-mistake/)

Comment: @cimmanon Increasing font-size = zooming in my comment. AKA `Ctrl` + `Scroll-wheel Up` or `Ctrl` + `+`. Let me rephrase: I endorse what you are saying fully. Good articles, by the way.